# Handling asynchronous call inside functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have two files where one.js has all modules and those modules are called in two.js file. But whenever I do get request, the function does not wait. I know node is asynchronous. Is there any way to handle the function without callbacks

```
//File one.js
function getRequest(){
var url = "https://api.hasoffers.com/v3/Affiliate_Affiliate.json";
        request(url, function (err, reponse, value) {
            return JSON.parse(value);
        });
}
exports.getRequest = getRequest;

//File two.js
var one = require(one.js);
console.log(one.getRequest()); //Returns undefined
```

I need to call function in two.js file in the same way `one.getRequest();` without any callback.

Comment: No. If the function returns the value immediately, it's not asynchronous by definition.

Comment: Whats the reason for down vote ?

Comment: "*without any callback*" - you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use promise or callback

```
function getRequest(callback){
var url = "https://api.hasoffers.com/v3/Affiliate_Affiliate.json";
    request(url, function (err, reponse, value) {
        callback(JSON.parse(value));
    });
}
```

//File two.js

```
var one = require(one.js);
one.getRequest(function(result){console.log(result)});
```

Comment: I know about callbacks but I have mentioned in my question that I need to call one.getRequest(). Is there any way to handle the result in one.js file ?

Comment: with this answer you handle the result in one.js, but with a function defined in two.js

Answer (score 0):

**you can use something like this:**

```
//File one.js
function getRequest(){
 this.url = "https://api.hasoffers.com/v3/Affiliate_Affiliate.json";

}
getRequest.prtotype.request=function() {
       request(this.url, function (err, reponse, value) {
        return JSON.parse(value);
    }); 
 });
 exports.getRequest = getRequest;



//File two.js
var one = require(one.js);
one=new one ();
 console.log(one.request());
```

Comment: if I add one more function inside one.js file, it throws me error like this.errorRes is not defined. getRequest.prototype.errorRes = function (msg) {
//Some object formation
        return JSON.parse(msg);
    }; and use the same inside getRequest.prtotype.request=function() {
       request(this.url, function (err, reponse, value) {
if(err){ return this.errorRes(error);}
        return JSON.parse(value);
    }); 
 });